# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}(x+2)^n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

Define the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}(x+2)^n.$$

All we know is that it converges in x=4. Why can't I say it converges absolutely in x=4?

Comment: Absolute convergence implies convergence but not the other way around. This is because you can construct sequences that alternate between positive and negative values that converge, whereas if we forced all the terms to be positive (by taking the absolute value) they would blow up to infinity. It's that the negative terms decreasing the value of the sum could be the only thing preventing it from blowing up to infinity. It's for this reason that you will need to prove absolute convergence separately, as it does not always follow from regular convergence.

Comment: Should the summation index be $n$, not $k$?

Comment: I corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, convergence at $x = 4$ tells you that the radius of convergence is at least $6$. If the radius is larger, then you get absolute convergence. If it is equal to $6$... well, things could go either way.

As a specific example, take
$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1) \cdot 6^n}.$$
Then, when $x = 4$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_n(x + 2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{n + 1},$$
which converges, though conditionally. The radius of convergence is exactly $6$ in this scenario, as expected.